# While compiling parse.com's anypic on my Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I was just looking at a few tutorials [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic). The first step says to create my own app on parse and to copy and paste my app/client id on AppDelegate.m. the problem is this. I found out that actually in AppDelegate.m which is located in Anypic iOS\Anypic, have under lined the part where I have to put my app/client id inside, just like this.

```
// ****************************************************************************
// Parse initialization
// [Parse setApplicationId:@"APPLICATION_ID" clientKey:@"CLIENT_KEY"];
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
// ****************************************************************************
```

Do I have to erase these and just make the third code valid, or did the system of atypic changed?

Answer (score 1):

You have to un comment line

```
// [Parse setApplicationId:@"APPLICATION_ID" clientKey:@"CLIENT_KEY"];
```

and provide your APPLICATION_ID and CLIENT_KEY which you created on parse.com without that you will not get access to your app of parse.